# Compatibility Check on Magento Product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am developing an Ecommerce app in magento 1.9.2
I need to filter products in product search which are compatible with other products.Compatibility will be checked according to different attributes of products.

I can build this by putting conditional code while searching but there needs to be more then 10 attribute checks at least so that will make my search slow. Can you guys suggest any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the advanced search. The URL will be: `website.com/catalogsearch/advanced/`

Open your website admin and go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes, and
open your attribute that you want to see in search.

Then go to the attribute > Properties > Frontend Properties > Use in Advance
Search > select Yes and save.